# Yii2 select query where multiple values

Tags: yii2, where-clause

When I want select where `IN` query, how to define multiple values in where clause?

Note on the `':k'=>1 and ':k'=>`, how to use it for 2 values?

```
$query = Model::find()->where('id = :id and type = :k' ,[':id'=>$id, ':k'=>1,':k'=>27])->count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions can be also defined using array syntax:

```
$count = Model::find()
    ->where([
        'AND',
        ['=', 'id', $id],
        ['IN', 'type', [1, 27]],
    ])
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using  IN  baded on an array 
assuming

```
$myArray = array(1,27);
$query = Model::find()->where(['IN', 'id', $myArray])
    ->andWhere('id = :id', [':id' => $id])->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way:

```
$types = [1, 27];
$query = Model::find()
    ->where(['id' => $id])
    ->andWhere(['type' => $types])
    ->count();
```

Yii2 will convert your `$types` array to `IN` condition. SQL query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> WHERE id = <id> AND type IN (1, 27);
```